# How to prevent eclipse-link from fetching lazy loaded attributes during DTO mapping?

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading, glassfish-3, data-transfer-objects

I've a bit paradox question, but I'll try to explain it as meaningful as possible.

**Background**

I have a 3-tiered application setup involving Glassfish 3.1.2.2, JPA 2.0 (eclipse-link 2.3.3), MySQL database and a stand-alone Swing-Client. I access the EJB's with JNDI by remote interfaces. Moreover I use static weaving in order to benefit from lazy loading complex relations. On the stand-alone Swing client, I use load groups to selectively fetch only the relations I really need.

**Goal**

For the purpose of reducing network traffic, I plan to transform the queried @Entity annotated database objects to DTO's (Data Transfer Objects, POJO's) by using this [model mapper](http://modelmapper.org/).

**The Big Issue**

During the mapping of the @Entity-Objects to the corresponding DTO's, the accessors of each field on the @Entity is accessed which in turn does catch up all the non-fetched (lazy loaded indirect lists) fields from the database, resulting in big objects again.

My goal is to map the lazy-fetched @Entitiy annotated objects as they are, without fetching  the intentionally non-fetched relations, in order to keep the objects as small as possible before they are being serialized and transfered to the remote client.

Any ideas ?

EDIT: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552379/prevent-dozer-from-triggering-hibernate-lazy-loading) from someone using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html), I'm looking for something similar for [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).

**What I tried so far (without success):**

- I detached the query result from the entity manager before mapping
  (still lazy fetching)
- clearing and closing the entity manager after querying and
  before DTO-mapping (still lazy fetching)
- declaring the queried
  List final (so that the lazy loading mechanism cannot

override attributes that are fetched afterwards, but it did)

**Many thanks for your help in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mapper cannot be configured to only map partial objects, then you can create a copy of the persistence object before passing it to the mapper.

Either use your own copy method that only copies the desired attributes, or you can use CopyGroups in EclipseLink,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#Copy_Examples

Comment: thanks james, the copy works as expected and is really fast. great :-)

Comment: After using copyGroup, if the getter of a non-copied attribute is called on the  clone object, I get a stackoverflowError. Is there anyway this can be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

A JPA independent way would be to use the PersistenceProvider.isLoadedWithReference(entity, attribute) for each field, and just use null in the DTO if it wasn't loaded.  This can be used to create the DTO directly, or in a CopyGroup as James suggested to make a scaled down entity instance of only fetched attributes.

Comment: many thanks for your valuable hint. I tried out your suggestion using conditional mapping, but these reflexion based mappers are just too slow and therefore I decided to implement my own copy functions using the decorator pattern.

Comment: hi chris, could you explain how to use the PersistenceProvider exactly? how do I get a contextual reference to the PersistenceProvider object? any sample code highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global property condition to conditionally map properties that are not lazy. Here's an example using JPA2's PersistenceUnitUtil:

```
final PersistenceUnitUtil unitUtil = entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(new Condition<Object, Object>() {
  public boolean applies(MappingContext<Object, Object> context) {
    return unitUtil.isLoaded(context.getSource());
  }
});
```