# Dozer cannot get Map. Javassist fault, is UnmodifiedMap

Tags: java, hibernate, dozer, javassist

I'm trying to copy an entitiy to create a new entity from Hibernate, with Dozer.

So far, everything has gone good. But one field has lazy loading turned on. Dozer expects a `Map` but since it's lazy loaded, it gets an `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap`.

Is there any way of forcing it to load the "real" `Map`-object?

I've tried setting a field-hint in the mapping XML, but to no avail.
Is there any good Javassist / Hibernate proxy thing to fix the Unmodifiable map problem?

Regards

Comment: Instead of Dozer I recommend using Mapstruct!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Javassist / Hibernate side of things, but have you tried creating a custom- converter for the field? That will essentially allow you to write your a mini java snippet to transfer the data in that specific field.

Comment: Any tips on how to do it? Is it through the setCustomFieldMapping? How do i get it to only convert a specified field?
Regards

Comment: Take a look at the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552379/prevent-dozer-from-triggering-hibernate-lazy-loading . This shows how to create the mapping and how to specify it in the mapping xml.